# Can I set a JS function to read HTML Table Cells?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the a HTML table with two variables that I want a function to read and display a text when true. For example: Trading hours of a store, if the number put into the first text box is 1130 and the second is 2100 then that would make the trading hours 11:30-9:00.

I then need a javascript function to read each one and display "Open" or "Closed" if the time is between those times or before/after.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="tradeFunction()">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
       <p align="center">Hours</p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p align="center">Open</p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p align="center">Closed</p>
    </td>
<tr>
    <td>
       <p id="1">------</p>
    </td>
    <td >
       <p id="2">1130</p>
    </td>
    <td >
       <p id="3">2100</p>
    </td>
</table>

<p id="hours"></p>

<script>
function tradeFunction() {
var greeting;
var time = new Date().getHours();
if (time < 1130) {
    greeting = "Closed";
} else if (time < 2100) {
    greeting = "Open";
} else {
    greeting = "Status: Unknown";
}
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = greeting;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I already have a set function but it's not very flexible and I need the ability to have the script call the cell and print the text.

EDIT: Would using the `var` tag work??? I'm not sure how to use it exactly but I do know that it's used for something like this?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use a front end framework, like jQuery, that will help you to retrieve and iterate over elements with specific selector (like <td> for example) in an efficient way

Comment: Well, since you already set ids for p tags...shouldn't be too hard? You can get innerHTML of p tags, or textContent, place it in vars (parseInt() it to get number!), and that's it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take care to close your table rows, in your HTML you are missing the

Then in order to compare the day time with the values you have in your table cells, you need it in the same format (hhmm).

The lines that are doing that are:

```
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.getHours() * 100 + date.getMinutes();
```

Also your initial condition for your if statement was not correct:
In english:
it is open if the current time is between the opening and the closing time.
which is traduced in:

```
if (time >= opening && time <= closing)
```

The final working code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="tradeFunction()">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p align="center">Hours</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p align="center">Open</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p align="center">Closed</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="1">------</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="2">1130</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="3">2100</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p id="hours"></p>

    <script>
        function tradeFunction() {
            var greeting = "Close";
            var date = new Date();
            var time = date.getHours() * 100 + date.getMinutes();
            var opening = parseInt(document.getElementById("2").innerHTML);
            var closing = parseInt(document.getElementById("3").innerHTML);
            if (time >= opening && time <= closing) {
                greeting = "Open";
            }
            document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = greeting;
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the data from your `p` tags and use it in your function like I did below. However there a few things wrong in there I'm not going to fix for you that you should figure out on your own. I put in a `console.log()` that shows you what value is being returned by `time`. You'll see that it is return only a 2 digit response for the hours. You're HTML data has a the minutes as well. You're going to want to adjust your function to parse the two separately and use that value in your conditional.

```js
function tradeFunction() {
var greeting;
var time = new Date().getHours();
console.log(time);
if (time < parseInt(document.getElementById('2').innerHTML)) {
    greeting = "Closed";
} else if (time < parseInt(document.getElementById('3').innerHTML)) {
    greeting = "Open";
} else {
    greeting = "Status: Unknown";
}
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = greeting;
}
```

```html
<body onload="tradeFunction()">

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
       <p align="center">Hours</p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p align="center">Open</p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p align="center">Closed</p>
    </td>
<tr>
    <td>
       <p id="1">------</p>
    </td>
    <td >
       <p id="2">1130</p>
    </td>
    <td >
       <p id="3">2400</p>
    </td>
</table>

<p id="hours"></p>
  
</body>
```

Comment: This does not work, the if conditions are wrong and the time variable is not correct with just getHours().

Comment: Well aware. I said it was wrong in my answer. I'm just not going to fix it for him so he can learn.

Comment: Indeed, I will add comments to my answer then